# Initializing a Java Swing JScrollPane to the bottom

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am trying to initialize a JScrollPane to start life at the bottom. I do not want it to scroll automatically after it is initially shown. The scroll pane does **not** contain a subclass of `JTextComponent`, but rather a `JPanel(GridLayout(0, 1))` containing many `JPanel`s.

I tried using `JViewport.scrollRectToVisible()` inside an event handler on the parent `Window` (`addComponentListener`:`componentShown`), but it did not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The scroll pane does not contain a
>   subclass of JTextComponent, but rather
>   a JPanel(GridLayout(0, 1)) containing
>   many JPanels.

Then you need to scroll the panel:

```
panel.scrollRectToVisible(...);
```

Or you should be able to use:

```
JScrollBar sb = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
sb.setValue( sb.getMaximu() );
```

Also, this code needs to be executed "after" the GUI is visible.

Comment: +1 I think it can be after `pack()` and before `setVisible()`.